# Member function call throws unimplemented feature

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have my own converter from varchar to number as a member function of my type t defined as follows:

```
member function toNumber (str in varchar) return number                     
is                                                                          
  num number;                                                             
begin                                                                       
  begin                                                                   
    num := to_number(str);                                              
  exception                                                               
  when others then                                                        
    num := null;                                                        
  end;                                                                    
  return num;                                                             
end;
```

Which I'm using in another member function:

```
 member function minTemperature return number                                
 is                                                                          
     minimum number;                                                         
 begin                                                                       
     select min(toNumber(temperature))                                       
     into minimum                                                            
     from date_table;                                               
     return minimum;                                                         
 end;
```

The type t is compiled correctly but when I call a member function which uses minTemperature like so `minimum := self.minTemperature();` oracle gives the unimplemented feature error.

Any idea on how to proceed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to reproduce your error.  I found it went away after I changed the line

```
    select min(toNumber(temperature))
```

to

```
    select min(self.toNumber(temperature))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I did not even suspect that the missing self could be the issue.

Comment: We shall now read from the Book of Coding Practices, verses 12 through 22: "And then St. Turing said, 'Oh Lord, bless this, thy code!". And the Lord did bless it. Then St. Turing said, "First shalt thou remember - never, no matter how cool thou mayst think it; never, under any circumstances; nay, not even if the king himself doth command thou to do so, NEVER (got that?) shalt thou use the name of a system  procedure as thine own, or thou, being naughty in the eyes of the Lord, shall be much infested with bugs!'. And the multitude did nod sagely, and thus it was, and so it is". Share and enjoy.